# Discord Bot Python 2.6 (How to make a sentence by embed)

Tags: python-3.6, discord.py

Maybe the title is not clear. But I hope the description is clear enough.
For example

```
@client.command()
async def info():
# the bot will embed
#in the first line the bot will say 'There is'
#and in the second line the bot withh say 'hah'
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

Just put a newline in the description:

```
await client.say(embed=Embed(description='there is\nhah'))
```